# IONIC 3 : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when generating APK File

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm facing problems when generating **apk** file. I get the following error.

Command : ionic cordova build android

Output :

```
> cordova build android
Android Studio project detected

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4
(node:17504) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (reje
ction id: 1): CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
(node:17504) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate th
e Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

[13:47:49]  lint finished in 8.47 s

This is the content of my rest file rest.ts

```
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

    @Injectable()
    export class RestProvider {

      private baseUrl = 'http://localhost/project/web/rest/mobile/v1/';
      private nomsvillesUrl = this.baseUrl + 'ville/nomsvilles/1';

      constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        console.log('Hello RestProvider Provider');
      }

      getNomvilles(): Observable<string[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.nomsvillesUrl)
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .catch(this.handleError);
      }

      private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res;
        return body || { };
      }

      private handleError (error: Response | any) {
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
          const err = error || '';
          errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
          errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
      }

}
```

This is the content of my main class main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RestProvider } from '../../providers/rest/rest';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-main',
  templateUrl: 'main.html',
})
export class MainPage {

  villes: string[]
  errorMessage: string

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public rest: RestProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.getVilles();
  }

  getVilles() {
    this.rest.getNomvilles().subscribe(
            villes => this.villes = villes,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
    }

}
```

Please help me ! I want to know how to handle Promise in order to prevent promise rejection.

Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has nothing related to your code. It's asking for **jdk** **1.8** or higher you can download it from this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). But first uninstall `jdk 1.9` you're using because it's not compatible with android.

Then create a environment variable `JAVA_HOME=C:\path\to\jdk\bin`

Comment: Now, it's ok. BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 26m 5s. You saved me. Thanks you